# How to convert Latlng value to double type

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, double, coordinates

I have Code: `LatLng latLng = (-7.11231243, 110.45345433);`
I want to convert this latlng to double value
like this : `double latlng = [-7.11231243, 110.45345433]`

***Can anyone help, please.***

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using something like [this class](https://pub.dev/documentation/latlong/latest/latlong/LatLng-class.html):

```dart
LatLng latLng = LatLng(-7.11231243, 110.45345433);
final doubleValues = [latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude];
```